# Filtering a user stream in an FQL query

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm attempting to query my own stream like so...

```
$fql_query = 
    "SELECT " .
        "post_id, actor_id, target_id, " .
        "message, updated_time, attachment, " .
        "likes, place, description, " .
        "description_tags, privacy " .
    "FROM stream " .
    "WHERE " .
        "filter_key in 
             (SELECT filter_key 
              FROM stream_filter 
              WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed')
```

Unfortunately, although this works, it returns a poor result set (not uncommon for FQL queries, from what I've been reading). I get 14 items, whereas I easily have the limit of 50 items within the last 30 days on my feed. I'm trying to run multiple queries to get more thorough data, but a query like this returns nothing:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message 
FROM stream 
WHERE filter_key in 
    (SELECT filter_key 
     FROM stream_filter 
     WHERE uid=me() AND 
         type='newsfeed') and 
    created_time < 1301746000
```

Does anybody know how I could get a more thorough data set from the queries? I don't even need all the data, but at the moment I'd say I'm getting < 20% of the total data I should (assuming the api should return me data limited to the past 30 days or 50 posts, as the documentation says should be returned).

It's probably worth noting I've tried running queries with different filter_key where clauses, to no avail. I'm concerned I'll have to use the graph api, which will involve pulling huge sets of data, when I'm only interested in very little.

What I actually want is to query (given two user ids) a set of news feed items that can be mutually seen by two people (posts made by their mutual friends, in other words). That seems like a pipe dream, given I can't even query my own news feed posts properly.